# Why doesn't my HTML checkbox work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website and my users are not able to click my checkbox on mobile devices. I have searched online and can not find a solution to this problem.

```css
.jg-c-register_label {
  display: grid;
}

.jg-c-register_label-text {
  color: #001e4b;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<label class="jg-c-register_label">
  <span class="jg-c-register_label-text" style="margin-bottom: -5px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="giftAid" name="giftAid" style="-webkit-appearance: auto;display: inline-block;">
    I am a UK Tax Payer. I want to Gift Aid this donation and any future donation I make on this
    platform until further notice.
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Does it work on _any_ mobile device, or does it fail on _all_? Which browsers? This needs more debugging details before it can be answered.

Comment: or you can provide the link of the page of your website where the issue exists.

Comment: Works for me on Android (Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: For the record, it does appear to be valid HTML. [<label>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Technical_summary) is allowed to have [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) as a child node, which appears to include [<span>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span). Additionally, `span` is allowed phrasing content too, which includes `input`

Comment: The username and password you have entered is invalid

Comment: @Capagris it works now!

Comment: then please provide the answer to your problem to help future users should they bump into the same problem as you did

Comment: @Capagris mean the username and password works... the checkbox doesn't work on mobile phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `-webkit-appearance: auto;` with `-webkit-appearance: checkbox;`  for the checkbox. It should work.

The checkbox does not work for my desktop also.

PS: Why have you put `-webkit-appearance: none;` and `display: none` kind of css properties when you have no custom css for you checkbox. Plus there is a lot of duplicate css in your code. Your default.css, global.css, normalize.css has same lines of code... Why...?????

Comment: The loads of duplicate css code is due to poor management when the site was being developed. I don't know how to clean it up because so many pages need the styling for one thing or another.

Comment: CSS need to be maintained while it is growing... Once it has grown, it is impossible to cut it short... But the bad impact of overgrown CSS is not that noticeable... So relax... Knowing the problem is half the problem solved. Cheers...!!!

Comment: Hi when people search up the site the two images come up despite the fact we are not mentioning the site name, i believe the crawlers can read text in images. Please can you delete both the images, and then I will delete this comment so the question can be accessed by others. @Sudipto Roy